# Visual C++ Error: "Identifier "IMSNMessenger" is undefined" - after adding tlb file

Tags: c++, visual-c++, import, typelib, msn-messenger

I am learning to work with the MSN Messenger API.

After adding the tlb file, and copy/pasting some example code, I noticed that in the Visual c++ IDE it's telling me about an undefined identifier.

Though once I compile the code, everything works fine.

I see the problem: The problem is that the IDE (the intellisense, more specifically) is not recognising any of the stuff inside the tlb file.

However, the compiler does!

I added the tlb file as such:

```
#import "MSNMessengerAPI.tlb" named_guids, no_namespace
```

Any ideas here? thanks!

Edit: may I add that the IDE does recognise the following:

```
MSNMessenger::IMSNMessenger
```

But not just

```
IMSNMessenger
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it should *not* recognize MSNMessenger::, you used the no_namespace attribute on the #import directive.  Taking a wild guess, maybe you started this first *without* that attribute and the IntelliSense parser isn't smart enough to recognize that you changed it.

Close your solution and delete the .ncb file in the project directory.  .sdf for VS2010.  Open it back up, the IS parser will rebuild the file.

Comment: It actualy worked after a few tries, don't know how, i didn't even close the project, it just all of a sudden started working...